# Nokia Lumia 520 w/win 8.1

Tags: pictures

I want to move my pictures over to the SD Card but I don't have a **picture app**.
So how do I move my pictures to the SD Card?

Thank You
Glenda

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **[Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/files/9wzdncrfj3pl)** app by Microsoft. Navigate to the folders where the pictures is present and move them to SD card.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the USB connection into PC and navigate to internal storage, go to Pictures and open other window into SD Card and navigate to the same folder, and cut and paste... It's more efficient if so much files or pictures. Good luck.